# How to dockerize Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, docker, dockerfile

When I try to create my custom image for flutter app, VSCODE stacks showing the following log:

[dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  2/13] RUN apt-get update &&   648.9s => => # enting => => # the time zones in which they are located. => => #   1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc => => #   2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV => => #   3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US => => # Geographic area:]

```
my Dockerfile is 
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Identify the maintainer of an image
LABEL version="0.0.1"
LABEL maintainer="abduidrism@gmail.com"

# Prerequisites
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl git unzip xz-utils zip libglu1-mesa openjdk-11-jdk wget

# Set up new user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash developer
USER developer
WORKDIR /home/developer

# Prepare Android directories and system variables
RUN mkdir -p Android/sdk
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT /home/developer/Android/sdk
RUN mkdir -p .android && touch .android/repositories.cfg

# Set up Android SDK
RUN wget -O sdk-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip
RUN unzip sdk-tools.zip && rm sdk-tools.zip
RUN mv cmdline-tools Android/sdk/cmdline-tools
RUN yes | /home/developer/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
RUN /home/developer/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;34.0.0" "platforms;android-33" "sources;android-33"
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/developer/Android/sdk/platform-tools"

# Download Flutter SDK
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/developer/flutter/bin"

# Run basic check to download Dark SDK
RUN flutter doctor
```

I checked my network connectivity, reinstalled docker, removed unused images and other caches. But it the problem is not solved.

Comment: `env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer setting `env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` ensures that the installation of packages via `apt-get` proceeds without requiring any user interaction.

In your case, you're encountering issues with the `apt-get update` step hanging during the Docker build process, setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` help in preventing any prompts or interactions that could potentially cause the build to hang.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Set environment variable to noninteractive mode
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```